# background not updating C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I'm having a bit of an issue when it comes to C#.

I'm trying to update the background of my form dynamically by downloading an image specified by the user.

My code to download the image (and update the form) looks like this:

```
 public bool getImgFromWeb(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //if response is okay, and it's an image
            //sometimes 404 will be okay, but will redirect to website.
            if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) &&
                (response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap(response.GetResponseStream());
                this.BackgroundImage = tempImg; //this line does nothing.
                this.Invalidate(); //to force the window to redraw
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the image your are trying to download does not exist. Please re-enter the image URL.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, an error: " + ex.Message + " occurred.");
            return false;

        }
```

any suggestions as to why my form isn't showing the updated background?

Thanks.

Comment: What is calling getImgFromWeb? On a different note you should rename the method to GetImgFromWeb to conform to the standard C# naming conventions.

Comment: what is the actual exception?

Comment: Add `this.Show();` to your code so you can see the form.  The wrong form.

Comment: Okay i'll give 'this.show()' a shot. No exception is thrown though, just no image pops up; and GetImgFromWeb is called from a custom dialog box (made from a form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your scenario and replaced this.Invalidate() with this.Refresh() and it worked. This is in Visual Studio 2012.

```
private void SetImageAsBackground(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(response.GetResponseStream());
                this.BackgroundImage = temp;
                this.Refresh();
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This isn't an image!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception: {0}", ex));                
        }
    }
```